# Control not visible to a Coded UI Test when opening the browser from within the test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I try to click a custom control on a web page as part of a Coded UI Test.
As part of the test, a browser windows is opened using

> browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri("http://www.mydomain/MyLoginPage"));

The test then logs in to our system and supposed to click a the custom tab control (similar to tabs on a browser).
It then fails saying that the control is not visible with the following error

> Result Message:    Test method MyTest.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1
>   threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException:
>   Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control.

Nothing seems to block the control but  TryGetClickablePoint() returns false, and FindMatchingControls() returns 1.

However, when i open the browser and perform the login myself, then start the test from the Click method, it works fine.

As far as i know, the custom control is generated using Mocha UI which is based on javascript(i don't 
know the specifics).
The test runs on IE 9.

I updated VS2012 with update 4 as suggested in this page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/17/coded-ui-mtm-issues-on-internet-explorer-with-kb2870699.aspx 
but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps the test tries to click the tab before it is made visible via Mocha UI's JavaScript?  Are you doing anything in the test to wait for the page to finish loading?

Comment: I already tried customControl.WaitForControlReady(), which continues immediately!
and playback.wait(10000).

Comment: Is it the same Click method you're using when you log in manually, or are you recording a different one?

Comment: - Put a breakpoint on the click method of your test.
- Start debugging the test.
- When the debugger hits the breakpoint, cancel debugging at this point, your application must be in the state where it is failing.
- Now right click your test in the solution explorer and select "edit with coded ui test builder" and assert your button to check if it's actually hidden or disabled.